# I get an error "Parameter is not valid" when trying to convert byte to image

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code:

```
string photo = "somedata";
byte[] byt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(photo);

string strModified = Convert.ToBase64String(byt);
byte[] photoData = Convert.FromBase64String(strModified);
Image img = cnvrtToImg(photoData);

public Image cnvrtToImg(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
     {
          return Image.FromStream(mStream);
     }
}
```

When the method `cnvrtToImg` is invoked, I get an error

> Parameter is not valid

Please give me a solution

Comment: Take a look at the answer i given to this question maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846010/c-sharp-show-image-database-for-each-usercontrol/24846062#24846062

Comment: so the error appears directly in the line Image img = CnvrtToImg(photoData) ?  In case if not did you try the code without "using" for the memory stream inside that method?

Comment: Why do you do the UTF8 and base64 roundtrip? What does `string photo` contain, and why would that represent valid image bytes? Please provide a [mcve], this is non-reproducible. _If_ `photo` contains base64-encoded image data, then it's simply `byte[] photoData = Convert.FromBase64String(photo);`.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/O6wtX2
Not OP, but here you go. It is reproducible. variable photoData is a byte array, but still considered invalid.

Comment: @jitenda that fiddle proves nothing. The bytes of encoding the string "somedata" in UTF-8 do not form a valid image format, so that's what the exception is telling you. This code simply makes no sense.

Comment: @CodeCaster I replaced it with some bytes from my own application. Still had the same problem. https://dotnetfiddle.net/O6wtX2 Here. This is byte array representation of an actual image, that my application saved using `File.ReadAllBytes`.

Comment: @jitendra you provided the same link. Again, this code reads the bytes of the string encoded in UTF-8, then converts that byte array to a base64 string, and then converts that string back to the earlier obtained byte array. It is unclear what this code is supposed to do, but what it currently does simply makes no sense. You cannot use UTF-8 to properly store binary image data.

Comment: Sorry, something is wrong. I forked the fiddle, saved the new one, but link is still the same. If I refresh the page, it opens new fiddle. If I follow link, it goes to old one. Weird. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think that System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 is not for image data, it is for text, not binary data.  UTF8 just can't do some binary sequence. Base64 is the choice if you need convert binary to text.
I test with this, and confirm the cnvrtToImg is correct:

```
class Program
{
    public static Image cnvrtToImg(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(mStream);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var file = File.Open(@"D:\0.jpg", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[file.Length];
            file.Read(buffer, 0, (int) file.Length);
            cnvrtToImg(buffer);
        }
    }
}

//finish
```

Comment: and I don't understand why you convert byte array to base64, and then convert back

Comment: I just confirm that cnvrtToImg is correct, the problem must be the source data problem.

Comment: can you modify your answer to incorporate that testing the method itself it works and that the problem must be from invalid source data? in its current form the answer sounds like "I think" instead of "It is so"